# Remove the values in an array based on the key

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of the given key-value format.

Array->

```
    [{
        "Name": "A",
        "Place": "A",
        "Comments": "A"
    },
    {
        "Name": "B",
        "Place": "B",
        "Comments": "B"
    },
    {
        "Name": "C",
        "Place": "C",
        "Comments": "C"
    }]
```

I need to remove all the values associated with the term "Place" using Javascript to get a result similar to this.

Array->

```
    [{
        "Name": "A",
        "Comments": "A"
    },
    {
        "Name": "B",
        "Comments": "B"
    },
    {
        "Name": "C",
        "Comments": "C"
    }]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: `array.map(item => { const {Place, ...rest} = item; return rest })`

Comment: @vsync Even shorter, `arr.map(({Place, ...rest})=>rest)`

Comment: @vsync I have tried what you've suggested. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AkhilKintali - are you using a modern browser? please elaborate in what way it doesn't seem to work for you

Comment: @vsync There was a mistake with the way I used it. 

It is working fine. Thank you!